Convert protobuf to JSON in Kotlin
Is there some easy way to convert protobuf message into JSON when using Kotlin? I have found multiple ways using JsonFormat in Java but this package does not seem to be available in Kotlin.
val myProto = MyProto.newBuilder().setId("id").build()
val json: String = ???


Perform like this:
    val myProto = MyProto.newBuilder().setId("id").build()
    val json: String = JsonFormat.printer().print(myProto)

    println(json)

Ensure you have the protobuf and protobuf-java-util dependencies
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.21.12")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.21.12")

Do check the version of the dependencies. It was working in mine.

Thanks, I was missing the util dependency
